# Gatsby - Contentful - Algolia Search Image Webhook

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, algolia, contentful

My Gatsby/Contentful blog is using Algolia to search through blog posts. Everything is working just fine, besides displaying images.

This is the Webhook Payload that Ive created in Contentful by using the Algolia template:

```
{
  "title": "{ /payload/fields/title/en-US}",
  "slug": "{ /payload/fields/slug/en-US}",
  "price": "{ /payload/fields/price/en-US}",
  "category": "{ /payload/fields/category/en-US}",
  "usages": "{ /payload/fields/usages/en-US}",
  "rating": "{ /payload/fields/rating/en-US}",
  "image": "https:{ /payload/fields/image/fields/file/url}"
}
```

My algolia query looks like this:

```
algolia.js


{
    allContentfulStrains {
      nodes {
        id
        title
        slug
        price
        usages
        rating
        category
        image {
          file {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now when I type gatsby build the data algolia is receiving is not structured right. View the image below. I want the structure to be - image:image.url so I can get the url of the image and past it in the hit component to display the images.

[algolia search image query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCWXD.png)

Is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: Can anybody help? :(

Comment: Someone has any clue what im doing wrong?